# Showing ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How to show that the map $f: \Bbb{Z_{10}} \rightarrow \Bbb{Z_{20}}$ defined as

$$f(x) = 16x$$ is a ring homomorphism.

I am trying to use the fundamental theorem of ring homomorphism.

I define $g : \Bbb{Z} \rightarrow \Bbb{Z_{20}}$ as $g(x) = 16x$

How can I show that $g$ is a ring homomorphism?

Now I can see that $10\Bbb{Z}$ is contained in Ker$g$.

Now I consider the canonical projection $\Pi$ : ${\Bbb{Z}}$ to $\Bbb{Z_{10}}$

Then there will exist a unique ring homomorphism from $h$: $\Bbb{Z_{10}}$ to $\Bbb{Z_{20}}$ such that $g = h \pi$  .

How to show that $h = f$?

Answer (score 1):

To show homomorphism you need to show two properties:

$f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$

$f(a\cdot b)=f(a)\cdot f(b)$

So here we have:

$f(a+b)=16(a+b)=16a+16b=f(a)+f(b)$

$f(a\cdot b)=16(a\cdot b)=16a\cdot16b=f(a)\cdot f(b)$

Therfore, $f$ is ring homomorphism.

Comment: Do note that $16(a\cdot b)=16a\cdot 16b$ is not trivial. You're using $16^2\equiv 16\pmod{20}$, so you need to mention that.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas You are right, I've used some modular arithmatic here, which I leave to the OP to prove.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please help further?